# After using lookbehind in regex replace the ouput with a value

Tags: regex

I'm trying to replace the output of a regex with another value. But i only seems to run the first regex.

What i have:

```
(?<=\bStatus:|Inhoud:\s1\sstuk\s)(\w+)
```

In a piece of text there are two possibilities; a word matching "**Status:**" and a word matching "**Inhoud: 1 stuk**". The output of running this regex is **1** for the first scenario and "**Dit**" for the second.

When the second scenario ("**Inhoud: 1 stuk**") with the output "**Dit**" is true i want to replace "**Dit**" with **0**.

First scenario example input:

> Oogpotlood (127) Oogschaduw (380) Staalwaren (8) Wenkbrauw (49) 1
>   Bourjois Concealer Healthy Mix Eclat Clari 051 Verbergt
>   onvolmaaktheden op een natuurlijke wijze. Inhoud: 1 stuk Status: 25
>   Verzenden € 10.85

Ouput is:

> 25

Second scenario example input:

> Nepwimpers (10) Oogpotlood (127) Oogschaduw (380) Staalwaren (8)
>   Wenkbrauw (49) 1 Bourjois Concealer Healthy Mix Eclat Clari 051
>   Verbergt onvolmaaktheden op een natuurlijke wijze. Inhoud: 1 stuk Dit
>   product is op dit moment niet op voorraad, je kunt het product niet
>   bestellen. Stuur mij een e-mail als dit product weer op voorraad is

Ouput is:

> Dit

So now i want to replace Dit with 0.

How do i do that?

Comment: Did you use the `g` modifier to extract all matches?

Comment: Tried to, but cannot find location where to put it, i'm not a regex fanatic. Sorry

Comment: is the word after `Status` always numbers?

Comment: also when you say output, do you want to replace that in the original string, or just print to console or something.

Comment: Yes word after status is always a number. Print to console is my wish.

Comment: What are you working with - a programming language or a text editor?

Comment: This is completely non-sensical. You're **matching** in the first case which is *ok* but in the second case you actually want to **replace** the **matched** string *Dit*. Which is impossible, you can't look right and left at the same moment, so is this situation. When you get the matched string, check if it is equals to "Dit" and output 0 if it is. You may even specify `if(matched == 'Dit product is op dit moment niet op voorraad'){output = 0;}else{output = matched;}`. Also it would be nice if you specified the language you're working with. Anyways, veel success :p

Comment: Dank je :) Problem is though, that it isn't a programming language. It is like a text editor. Only Regex available.

Comment: So what is this that _is like a text editor_?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you just want to find this

```
Inhoud: 1 stuk Dit
```

and replace it with

```
Inhoud: 0 stuk Dit
```

no regex needed.